# Which of the following are correct?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function. Then which of the following are correct

1. $f$ is constant if  range  of $f$ is contained in a straight line
2. $f$ is constant if $f$ has uncountably many zeros
3. $f$ is constant if $f$ is bounded on $\{z\in\mathbb{C}: Re(z)\leq 0\}$
4. $f$ is constant if $Re(f)$ is bounded.

If $Re(f)$ is bounded by C-R equations i got f is constant.I am struggling with the other options. help me!

Comment: Consider $e^z$ as an example.

Comment: this is example for 3 only. Is it?

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj8066Z8KDJAhVJuBQKHR5WDm4QFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stat.uchicago.edu%2F~lekheng%2Fcourses%2F185f09%2Fmath185f09-hw7sol.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFqbIT9HP77m3BY5Fe7tEkh5Z7sWA&sig2=v5cD1IjD7Y_vghol4xfjxg

Comment: Yes it is for 3.

Comment: Can anyone please elaborate #4?

Answer (score 2):

Since you have 4, note for 1, that multiplying the function by an appropriate constant will make the line parallel to the imaginary axis.

2 requires that the zeros of $f$ have a limit point.

Michael M has answered 3.

Answer (score 0):

*$Hint$-*Remember the Louiville's theorem: An entire function $f$ which is bounded on $\mathbb C$ must be a constant.

- Options 1, 2 and 4 are direct consequences of the above statement. Only 3 has a counterexample i.e. $e^z$ as $|e^z|=|e^x||e^{iy}|=e^x<1$ for $Re(z)<0$